# Move cursor across html tags in text editor

Tags: html, sublimetext2, text-editor, shortcut

How can I move the cursor across HTML tags in a text editor like Sublime Text or anything else instead of pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> (not a direct move) keys so many times?
Is there any shortcut available?, if not, how can I create one for Sublime Text editor?
Here is how I want to move the cursor.

```
    <html>
       <p>
            "a"
       </p>
       <div>
            "b"
       </div>
    </html>
```

I want move the cursor from position a to b using a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Sublime but I have heard that it's very similar to Textmate, it may actually be based on Textmate, I'm not sure.

I am familiar with Textmate 1.5 though, and it does have a feature like this which allows you to setup tab triggers and templates by using the built in Bundle Editor.

*note: it's worth noting that there is a newer version of Textmate available.  I believe the current version is 2.0 but I tried it and decided to stick with 1.5 because 2.0 implemented some major changes and I preferred to stick with what I was familiar and happy with.*

A very basic example of how tab triggers can be used in Textmate would be..

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="$1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td height="$2"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

This is a simple table spacer that I use in emails rather than using transparent shims.  By nesting a table within a table it will prevent it from collapsing and works as a cross-compatible alternative to transparent gif images for email layouts.

By setting this up in Textmate, all I have to do is type `tspace` followed by a <kbd>Tab</kbd> and this code automatically populates at the position of the cursor.  Subsequent <kbd>Tab</kbd>'s will jump the cursor to each $ notation, which is Textmate's own syntax.

So `tspace` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> generates the code, + <kbd>Tab</kbd> jumps to $1 where I then fill in the appropriate value, + <kbd>Tab</kbd> jumps to $2 where I fill in the appropriate value + <kbd>Tab</kbd> jumps to the end of the code block.

*note: you can also set it up where any placeholder is repeated so if I notate $1 in more than one location, it will automatically populate everywhere that variable is, the first time I fill it in.*

This is only the most basic of examples.  There are other similar features in Textmate, and they are only limited by how complex you set them up to be.

---

Though, as I mentioned, I'm not familiar with Sublime, I did look into it briefly and found [this article](http://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/top-features-of-sublime-text/quickly-insert-text-and-code-with-sublime-text-snippets/) which outlines the exact same functionality that I've described and how it works within Sublime.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer @dcc. But unfortunately textmate is not available for Linux/Windows.